# Where is the documentation page for ActiveRecord data types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I can't find the active record documenation page that has a list of all the data types.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you're talking about the types for migrations, e.g. string, integer, datetime, etc, then you want [**ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html), the [**column**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) method. (Rails 5 edit: see also connection.[**add_column**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column).)

As of this update, the standard types are:

- `:primary_key`
- `:string`
- `:text`
- `:integer`
- `:bigint`
- `:float`
- `:decimal`
- `:numeric`
- `:datetime`
- `:time`
- `:date`
- `:binary`
- `:boolean`

The implementation of `:decimal` is different with each database, so I'd avoid it if possible. You may use a type not in this list as long as it is supported by your database (for example, `:polygon` in MySQL), but this will not be database agnostic and should also be avoided.

Comment: Just a matter of choice, or any particular reason to like ApiDock over official docs?

Comment: @Swanand It's the same content, of course, but the navigation is better. And the ability to see how much something has changed in various Rails versions is invaluable.

Comment: @Swanand The user-created notes are very useful too in areas where the documentation alone isn't very helpful.

Comment: Note that these have remained the same in Rails 4.

Comment: `:timestamp` seems to be no longer on the list, and is treated as `:datetime` (appears as `:datetime` in `db/schema.rb`). Or is [probably just alias](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1.rc4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L364-366) for `:datetime`.

Comment: It appears that `:timestamp` was removed from Rails 4.2+

Comment: Note that the documentation of the types has now been moved: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column

Answer (score 6):

You can also see **ActiveRecord data types** in sources. Each DBMS adapter contains its own mapping. For example, in MySQL case look at this file: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L148 or get it by this line of code for current DBMS adapter:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.native_database_types.keys
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the default mappings of types for database adapters:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

> Note this is based on Rails Source Code dated 13th Feb 2015 (Rails
>   4.2)

In case someone wants to see how these datatypes get mapped into the database you are using.

You can grab easily at rails source code at github.

***For example***

> Rails data types to mysql datatyes mapping.

```
NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES = {
        :primary_key => "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY",
        :string      => { :name => "varchar", :limit => 255 },
        :text        => { :name => "text" },
        :integer     => { :name => "int", :limit => 4 },
        :float       => { :name => "float" },
        :decimal     => { :name => "decimal" },
        :datetime    => { :name => "datetime" },
        :time        => { :name => "time" },
        :date        => { :name => "date" },
        :binary      => { :name => "blob" },
        :boolean     => { :name => "tinyint", :limit => 1 }
      }
```

Found at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L148

And if some one wants postgreSQL here you go.

```
NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES = {
        primary_key: "serial primary key",
        bigserial: "bigserial",
        string:      { name: "character varying" },
        text:        { name: "text" },
        integer:     { name: "integer" },
        float:       { name: "float" },
        decimal:     { name: "decimal" },
        datetime:    { name: "timestamp" },
        time:        { name: "time" },
        date:        { name: "date" },
        daterange:   { name: "daterange" },
        numrange:    { name: "numrange" },
        tsrange:     { name: "tsrange" },
        tstzrange:   { name: "tstzrange" },
        int4range:   { name: "int4range" },
        int8range:   { name: "int8range" },
        binary:      { name: "bytea" },
        boolean:     { name: "boolean" },
        bigint:      { name: "bigint" },
        xml:         { name: "xml" },
        tsvector:    { name: "tsvector" },
        hstore:      { name: "hstore" },
        inet:        { name: "inet" },
        cidr:        { name: "cidr" },
        macaddr:     { name: "macaddr" },
        uuid:        { name: "uuid" },
        json:        { name: "json" },
        jsonb:       { name: "jsonb" },
        ltree:       { name: "ltree" },
        citext:      { name: "citext" },
        point:       { name: "point" },
        bit:         { name: "bit" },
        bit_varying: { name: "bit varying" },
        money:       { name: "money" },
      }
```