# How to represent a value from an object as boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following object  is being returned from a SQL call:

```
#<Health:0x007fc8533f2de8 @type=:diabetic, @value="N", @data_source=nil, @measured_at=nil>
```

The value could be 'Y' or 'N' and can be accessed as `health.value`.

How do I represent this value as a boolean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Health` is a model you can do something like:

```
def diabetic?
  value.upcase == 'Y'
end
```

in the model's file.

Another more generic approach with a different function name (see comments) is:

```
def value?
  value.upcase == 'Y'
end
```

Comment: I think that `has_condition?` would probably be a better function name given that the `type` may not always be `diabetic`

Comment: `has_x?` is not a very good naming convention, unless it's actually indicating some kind of ownership. [the style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#bool-methods-prefix)

Comment: Why not call it `true?`?

Comment: @RobinDaugherty so it would be something like ```has_diabetes?```. Having second thoughts for adding this...

Comment: `has_diabetes?` would make sense on a different model, like `Person` (and I think it fits with the style guide in that case). But in this model, it would make more sense to stick to the existing naming conversion and call it `value?`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question, but you seem to be using ActiveRecord.

If you are able to change the structure of the database, I would recommend doing so. Storing a boolean value as a string is not a good practice.

The `boolean` column type will store a native boolean value [if the database supports it, and will translate if not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28098665/1589422). ActiveRecord automatically adds a predicate method to your model.

So if you have a boolean column named `value`, there will also be a method named `value?` that will return either true or false. "[Automagical ?-methods for boolean attributes in ActiveRecord](https://makandracards.com/makandra/607-automagical-methods-for-boolean-attributes-in-activerecord)" is another example.

Answer (score -1):

```
{"Y" => true, "N" => false}[health.value.upcase]
```

Comment: While this would work, it suffers from readability. A simple comparison of the value to `'Y'` would be easier to read --> understand --> maintain.

Comment: That's clever. That's not a compliment. `(health.value.upcase == "Y")` would be clearer and more concise.

Comment: The only reason I considered not doing a simple comparison, is if there is a reason to handle cases other than "y" or "n".   but it does look like the use case is only "Y","N" so this is a bit over engineered.